# How to add captcha in yii wform

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I am using "wForm" extension for forms. I want to add "captcha" in my form.
I have tried "myCaptcha" component for "cForm".
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/733/how-to-show-a-captcha-in-cform/ 
but i am getting the following error

> "WForm" and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "MyCaptcha".

how can i use the "cform captcha in wForm"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the extension [cCaptcha extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/captcha-extended/)

1) Unzip CaptchaExtended.zip files into ../protected/extensions/captchaExtended/.

2) Register class paths to CaptchaExtendedAction and CaptchaExtendedValidator, e.g. in components/controller.php:

```
public function init(){
    // register class paths for extension captcha extended
    Yii::$classMap = array_merge( Yii::$classMap, array(
        'CaptchaExtendedAction' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.captchaExtended').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'CaptchaExtendedAction.php',
        'CaptchaExtendedValidator' => Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.captchaExtended').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'CaptchaExtendedValidator.php'
    ));
}
```

3) Define action in controller, e.g. SiteController:

```
public function actions(){
    return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CaptchaExtendedAction',
            // if needed, modify settings
            'mode'=>CaptchaExtendedAction::MODE_MATH,
        ),
    );
}
```

4) Define client validation in model::rules():

```
public function rules(){
    return array(
        array('verifyCode', 'CaptchaExtendedValidator', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
    );
}
```

5) add the following in your view file (in your form)

```
$this->widget('CCaptcha'); //for captch image
echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'verifyCode'); //text field to enter captcha text
```